# Navigation options in a wizard: next, previous, exit and save (finish later), exit without saving - too many?

Tags: forms, gui-design, wizard

I am designing a linear wizard for filling in a form (configuring an order). When filling in the form, the actions at each step are:

- move to the next step (saving entered data);
- move to the previous step (saving entered data);
- exit saving the entered data as a draft;
- exit without saving.

The user also has a possibility to go back to any step to edit entered data and the changes do not affect any of the next steps. So if the user is editing the data, the available possibilities are:

- move to the next step (saving entered data);
- move to the previous step (saving entered data);
- return where to left from without saving changes;

and possibly:

- return where he left from saving entered data;

It looks like there will be too many navigation choices for the poor user! Any suggestions how to solve it?

P.S. The completed steps will be additionally available by clicking on them directly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you clarify what scenario "Previous" and "Next" would not be adequate in?

Comment: Let us say that at step 4 (overview and confirmation) the user decides to make corrections in the data adddd at step 2. He clicks on step 2 in top navigation and makes corrections. Then it may be easier for him to go directly to overview (step 4).

Comment: Are all questions mandatory for the user to fill/complete in order to complete the task?

Answer (score 1):

I think I would change them just a little bit:

- Navigating back and forth through the ordering process having my data saved is something I would definitely expect.
- The data should be saved all the time, so I think that "Exit saving data" as an action is not necessary (as they are saved anyway).
- Therefore, "exit without saving" could be changed to "Cancel the order", which of course should not be super prominent.